# php make google and facebook access my site

Tags: php, facebook, google-crawlers

I want to access my site from ONLY my country and I want to google and facebook can access to my site. So I looked to the these pages:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#crawl
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en
And I writed this php code:

```
<?php
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if (!preg_match("/facebook/", $agent) && !preg_match("/bingbot/", $agent) && !preg_match("/Googlebot/", $agent) && $agent != 'Facebot')
{
$country = geoip_country_code_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if($country != 'AZ')
{
$error = 'Sorry, we can only serve to Azerbaijan!';
include('error.php');
die;
}
}
?>
```

It works on facebook. But when I want to get my page speed results with google, i get "Sorry, we can only serve to Azerbaijan!" error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the one of the user agent of Google Page Speed Insight

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; Google Page Speed Insights) Chrome/27.0.1453 Safari/537.36
```

Change this

```
!preg_match("/Googlebot/", $agent)
```

to this

```
!preg_match("/Google(bot| Page Speed Insights)/", $agent)
```

Comment: If I change this everyone who uses google chrome can access to my site